# Game Architecture and State Design

Tags: java, game-engine, state

This is probably going to be a very broad question, but I would like to know what is the best approach to structure and design a game with multiple states in Java.

I have started to design a Battleship game with multiple states ( AI vs AI, Human vs Human, etc..).

It looks like this:

[image: Imgur]

Unfortunately, my code has become very disorganized and confusing due to the multiple changes in state logic and resources the game requires. I wanted to find a better way to clean up my code and organize it in a way that is easier to maintain and is not as complex.

So what is the best approach to maintain a good design for games like this one?

Comment: A [Model–view–controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) would be my primary suggestion, this way you can separate the individual requirements into areas of pluggable responsibility and easily interchange them.  For example, the view for each of the states shouldn't really change, but the way the data is model might and the way that the program is controlled will...for example...ps - Nice space screen ;)

Comment: My code is based on the Model-View-Controller, yet everything seems to be very dirty and confusing. Changing from state to the other requires changing from one panel to the other and loading a different logic based on the state the game it is in. I was looking for a way to better organize the states' different logics and resources such as in the State design pattern.

Comment: Changing states, assume the primary view doesn't change, should only require a change in model and maybe controller.  Without seeing your code, it's difficult to be 100% sure, but switching from the menu to a game state may require you to pass through a "setup" state in order to be able to build the required models/controllers.  Again, this is just another MVC state as each "game state" should be it's own MVC, where the primary game is another MVC...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both [inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29) and [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) together to solve this problem. I assume you have a main game class or level class, which you want to store this data in. You would want to create an interface called `GameState`, and create all of your subclasses (AI vs AI, Human vs Human, etc...). Then add a variable to your level class:

```
class MainGame{
    GameState state;

    public MainGame(){
        state = new HumanVsHumanState();
    }
    public void update(){
        state.update();
    } 
    //etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I particularly like the abstraction provided by the FlashPunk 2D Game Engine. Within this framework you can identify the following abstractions:

- The Context (a static class used to access global properties and functions)
- The Engine (main game class)
- Worlds (each of the possible states of the game)
- Entities (the objects inside each world)

Following this, the code would look like this:

```
class MyGame extends Engine {
    MyGame() {
        // Here we code high level setup
        Context.world = new MenuWorld()
    }
}

class MenuWorld extends World {
    MenuWorld() {
        // Here we add the elements of the menu
        this.add(new CompCompButton());  
        this.add(new HumanHumanButton());
    }
}

class CompCompButton extends Entity {
    CompCompButton() {
        // Here we setup button properties
    }

    // This is a callback function that is automatically called by the framework.
    void Update() {
        if (Input.mousePressed()) {
            onClick();
        }
    }

    void onClick() {
        Context.world = new CompCompWorld();
    }
}
```

Note the use of the static Context class. This class should implement all the logic for rendering the new world.

The HumanHumanButton class implementation is basically the same as the CompCompButton class. The only difference is that the onClick function now changes the current world to HumanHumanWorld. In fact, you could implement a generic Button Class and then extend it in order to have cleaner code.

You can read more about FlashPunk in its Web Site. It would be worth to look for Java Game Engines as well, there is one called LWJGL though I can tell nothing about it since I have not worked with it.

Hope that helps.